# How to prevent the android system from killing an app?

Tags: applications, task-management

I have rooted my phone and use Swapper. an app that creates a linux like swap simulation w/o actually partitioning the sd card...

I observed that this app gets killed every now and then thus not allowing me to get full benifits of it.

I do not use any task killer.The android system kills it.How do I prevent andreoid from doing this?

Comment: As far as I can tell, Google deliberately added this *rude* behavior (of killing processes that don't actually need to be killed) in 2.2.  This is really a deal-breaker for me, and I just don't know what to do.